# ASP.net MVC get current viewengine

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to get the currently used `ViewEngine` from the `ControllerContext` or the `ViewEngineCollection`? I would like to be able to do say the following `ViewEngines.GetCurrent`. I know that I can make an extension for that method but I have no idea on how to implement this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What do you need that for?

Comment: I'm in the process of extending the Mobile view engine that Scott Hanselmann posted. The way it is implemented now isn't very extensible. I'm working on a smart opt out system (and some other improvements) for that view engine and I would like to enable/disable the mobile functionality of the currently used view engine)

Comment: In the context of the controller, there is no currently used view engine. One won't be resolved until it's actually render time.

Comment: *I'm in the process of extending the Mobile view engine that Scott Hanselmann posted* **You should read the comments**, I also don't like he's approach and if you simply redirect to the proper View in your controller you do get much more control on what's going on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ViewEngineCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493042.aspx) to look up the `ViewEngine` associated with a particular view.

```
ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(controllerContext,
                                                       "myView","myMaster");
IViewEngine viewEngine = result.ViewEngine;
```

See here for more [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewenginecollection.findview.aspx).

Comment: how to do that on core 2.0?